# How to prove $NG_i$ is normal in $NG_{i+1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group, $N \unlhd G$ and $G_i \unlhd G_{i+1} \le G$, then $NG_i \unlhd NG_{i+1}$?

The reason given for why the conclusion is true is that because "$N$ and $G_{i+1}$ each normalize $NG_i$ inside of $G$."

I don't exactly understand the wording in the quote and need help understanding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you need to show that $xyx^{-1}\in NG_i$ for all $x\in NG_{i+1}$ and $y\in NG_i$. Write $x=ng$ and $y=n'g'$ for $n,n'\in N$, $g\in G_{i+1}$, and $g'\in G_i$. Then,
$$
xyx^{-1}=(ng)(n'g')(g^{-1}n^{-1})=n(gn'g^{-1})(gg'g^{-1})n^{-1}$$
Note that $n(gn'g^{-1})=n''\in N$ since $N\lhd G$. Also, $gg'g^{-1}=h\in G_i$ because $G_i\lhd G_{i+1}$. Hence,
$$xyx^{-1}=n''hn^{-1}=n''(hn^{-1}h^{-1})h.$$
Again, $n''(hn^{-1}h^{-1})=n'''\in N$ as $N\lhd G$. Finally, as $h\in G_i$, we have
$$xyx^{-1}=n'''h\in NG_i$$
as required.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you please also comment on what the wording in the quotes mean?

Comment: It means that both $N$ and $G_{i+1}$ are subgroups of $N_G(G_i)\leq G$.